# Long hierarchical (specific) CSS property vs direct property

Tags: php, html, css

I was wonder what is the benefit of been specific with css vs make it in the short way and mention directly (only) the property.

```
<style>

html #first span.myred
{
    color:red;
}
// VS
.myred
{
    color:red;
}

</style>
<html>
<div id="first">
    Hello&nbsp;<span class="myred">World!</span>
</div>

<div id="second">
    Hello&nbsp;<span class="myred">World!</span>
</div>
</html>
```

Yes I understand that it might solve name SAME PROPERTY NAME conflicts but consider that I will carefully check that there won't be doubles is there any other advantages to the long (specific) method ?

Answer (score 1):

So this gets into opinion territory, but, in general, the first selector you listed `html #first span.first_span` is what is termed and "over qualified selector". They are significantly less performant, and come from people not understanding how to efficiently structure their css to avoid specificity conflicts. In short `.class-name` is a better choice than `body div ul li a.list-link'

Comment: Can you say in other words ALWAYS use the short method ? ...well, unless ?

Comment: There will always be some nested selectors. How much and when will depend on what your overall css architecture looks like, how much access you have to the markup (html) and who else has dirtied up your codebase (or how specific the code of some framework you are using is). Some basic concepts on css methodology https://smacss.com/ http://oocss.org/ there are plenty of different approaches out there.